# Bash: any command to replace strings in text files?

Tags: bash, shell, replace, text-processing

I have a hierarchy of directories containing many text files. I would like to search for a particular text string every time it comes up in one of the files, and replace it with another string. For example, I may want to replace every occurrence of the string "Coke" with "Pepsi". Does anyone know how to do this? I am wondering if there is some sort of Bash command that can do this without having to load all these files in an editor, or come up with a more complex script to do it.

I found [this page](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/unix-linux-replace-string-words-in-many-files/) explaining a trick using sed, but it doesn't seem to work in files in subdirectories.

Comment: I hate it when this happens.  Four answers that are very close in under 3 minutes.  Sometimes answering these questions becomes a race... very stresfull... waiting for the yellow bar at the top saying "load answers"

Comment: Many of you submitted suggestions that worked. I accepted theatrus's simply because he replied first.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use `sed` in combination with `find`. For instance:

```
find . -name "*.txt" | xargs sed -i s/Coke/Pepsi/g
```

or

```
find . -name "*.txt" -exec sed -i s/Coke/Pepsi/g {} \;
```

(See the man page on find for more information)

Comment: also,if you're using a combination of `find` and `xargs`, particularly in a script, it's always best to use `find -print0` and `xargs -0`, to guard against files with spaces in their names

Comment: @mikez302: Please take Martin's comment into account. `xargs` is often not required and should usually be used with the `-0` switch. The second solution is much better.

Comment: `find` also has the option to spawn only a single process for all results if you use `+` instead of `;` as the delimiter to `-exec`: `find . -name '*.txt' -exec sed -i 's/Coke/Pepsi/g' '{}' +`

Answer (score 4):

IMO, the tool with the easiest usage for this task is `rpl`:

```
rpl -R Coke Pepsi .
```

(`-R` is for recursive replacement in all subdirectories)

Comment: Links: [Original](http://www.laffeycomputer.com/rpl.html), [Debian](http://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=rpl), [Ubuntu](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=rpl), [Fedora](https://admin.fedoraproject.org/pkgdb/acls/name/rpl?_csrf_token=4f507dd0ecebb1f7d7ec166507562d25be5a7cef)

Comment: @Dennis: Thanks! I should have thought about adding at least one of them.

Answer (score 3):

Combine sed with find like this:

```
find . -name "file.*" -exec sed -i 's/Coke/Pepsi/g' {} \;
```

Answer (score 3):

`find . -type f -exec sed -i 's/old-word/new-word/g' {} \;`

Answer (score 2):

I usually do it in perl. However watch out - it uses regexps which are much more powerful then normal string substitution:

```
% perl -pi -e 's/Coke/Pepsi/g;' $filename
```

**EDIT** I forgot about subdirectories

```
% find ./ -exec perl -pi -e 's/Coke/Pepsi/g;' {} \;
```

Answer (score 2):

you want a combination of `find` and `sed`

Answer (score 0):

You may also:

Search & replace with find & ed

http://codesnippets.joyent.com/posts/show/2299

(which also features a test mode via -t flag)