# Mass Replace String in same directly and sub folder

Tags: linux, ssh, sed, grep

I am trying to use the following way to replace my string

```
grep -rl matchstring . | xargs sed -i 's/string1/string2/g'
```

What I want to achieve is actually currently I got a hardcode domain name like

```
http://account.mysmallwebsite.com
https://account.mysmallwebsite.com
```

Because this is quite inflexible, I would prefer just

```
<?php echo $domainName;?>
```

the variable of domainName will be set in a php file and all the files will include this file so in future if I change domain, it will be easier to just change 1 place rather than multiple pages.

and replace all occurrence of the website

```
http://account.mysmallwebsite.com
https://account.mysmallwebsite.com
```

with the echo string, but how do I achieve it through command line at putty shell ssh

Comment: Related: [Bash: any command to replace strings in text files?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2860170/bash-any-command-to-replace-strings-in-text-files)

Comment: @fedorqui , if I do this find . -name "*.txt" -exec sed -i s/Coke/Pepsi/g {} \; , how do I change the string to make it work for http and https with my pattern, I am quite bad with regex sorry for asking

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following:

```
find . -name "*.php" -exec sed -r -i.bak 's#http(s?)://account.mysmallwebsite.com#<?php echo $domainName;?>#g' {} \;
```

#### Explanation

- `find . -name "*.php" -exec ... {} \;` this looks for files whose name ends with `.php` and performs the command indicated in `...`.
- `sed -r -i.bak 's#http(s?)://account.mysmallwebsite.com#<?php echo $domainName;?>#g' file`:

  - this looks for `http(s?)://account.mysmallwebsite.com`, that is, `http` + maybe an `s` + `://account.mysmallwebsite.com` and replaces it with `<?php echo $domainName;?>`.
  - Note the usage of `#` as separator instead of the typical `/`, so that we don't have to escape the slashes in the URL.
  - The `-i.bak` creates a backup file with `.bak` extension, while the original one gets in-place edited.
  - You can also "play" with `-maxdepth` value, to define how many levels of subdirectories you want to work on. For example, `-maxdepth 1` will just check the current directory, while `-maxdepth 2` will also include the sub folders of the given directory.

Graphically:

```
s#http(s?)://account.mysmallwebsite.com#<?php echo $domainName;?>#g
^      ^^^^                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
| ^^^^^^|^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^       substitution        ^
|       |     look for this text                     replace all matches
|      may be an "s"
^  
search
```

See the `sed` command in action:

```
$ cat a
hello
http://account.mysmallwebsite.com
https://account.mysmallwebsite.com
httpss://account.mysmallwebsite.com
bye

$ sed -r 's#http(s?)://account.mysmallwebsite.com#<?php echo $domainName;?>#g' a
hello
<?php echo $domainName;?>
<?php echo $domainName;?>
httpss://account.mysmallwebsite.com
bye
```

Comment: kind of explaination that is exhaustive and pretty well explicit +1